# TemplateRef api change in Angular2 RC0

Tags: angular

In beta release, I was accessing the template to repeat for a data component via;

```
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef;
```

With RC0, the error happens is "Generic type 'TemplateRef require 1 type argument(s)"

What kind of type I should define as the generic type? It could be any html content as in;

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datalist

I believe;

```
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

should work as I don't necessarily need any specific type except $implicit.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be working in RC4 using

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Comment: could you please help me understand what other generic parameters are accepted for `TemplateRef`?